# Documentation for spatial USAID DDL data

Tags: geospatial, usaidopen, documentation

I am engaged in a project, Climate Resilient Ecosystem and Livelihood, where we generated and/or compiled various spatial data (satellite images, ArcGIS featureclasses, spreadhseets, static maps, etc.) related to protected areas of Bangladesh. As a USAID requirement, we need to submit these data to a DDL system.

I have submitted [this form](https://www.usaid.gov/data/DDLSubmissions) and created an account with USAID. I see the DDL space allows users to upload files. I've been looking for guidance on spatial data standards and found out that they must be in a non-proprietary format. I've also been able to find some data that are public; this data contains CSVs and accompanying PDFs as documentation.

I would like to know specific guidance for spatial data and metadata standards for USAID. An example folder would be helpful, like those found alongside the [CSV data in the Sample DDL folder](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6dqpkopo2homa5s/bangladesh-integrated-household-survery-dataset.zip?dl=0).

I am stumbling on where from to start. I found another DDL folder that I think is spatial data related work where from I might get the direction but it is restricted see [here](https://www.usaid.gov/data/dataset/2f00ad88-af2e-4c34-b2d2-e8c598323ba9).

Has anyone worked with the USAID DDL system for spatial data before?

Comment: Have you considered speaking with someone who manages the support system for the USAID DDL? Do they publish a list of what formats they require data to be in? I feel like many of your questions are best answered via their 1-on-1 support.

Answer (score 2):

USAID is in the process of finalizing its geospatial data standards, which we expect to make available in 2017.  As stated in our [Frequently Asked Questions](https://www.usaid.gov/data/frequently-asked-questions#Q7) (FAQs), datasets must be submitted to the DDL "in a machine-readable, non-proprietary format."  As a matter of practice, the DDL will accept proprietary formats ***as long as*** the submitter also provides a non-proprietary format. This holds true for geospatial datasets.  For more clarity on definitions of terms, please see [FAQ#2](https://www.usaid.gov/data/frequently-asked-questions#Q2)

If you have already completed the [DDL Submission Form](https://www.usaid.gov/data/DDLSubmissions), our DDL staff will reach out to you with a link where you can upload your data files.  If you have not received that link, please contact our staff at opendata@usaid.gov for assistance.

Comment: yes I have that link  where to upload data but i need the guidance on how to organise the data before uploading. I have ~10gb data! So I need structure for organising this data and metadata standards for spatial data.It would be great if I get a dummy structure at least.

Answer (score 1):

Draft geospatial standards are now posted for comment / feedback at www.usaid.gov/data.